# Android nfcA.transceive(byte[] command), what is the sequence of commands to fetch data from nfc device?

Tags: android, request, tags, nfc, mifare

I have a few questions regarding nfcA. I am integrating a NFC device with my android application to fetch the data from the device. I am successful in connecting the NFC device using nfcA.connect(). Card is **NXP MIFARE Ultralight**. This is my NFC device info:

[image]

**QUESTION**: What should be the byte[] commands to send to nfcA.transceive(byte[] commands) to fetch the data from the device. When i try to read the pages by using the following command:

```
 byte[] commands = new byte[]{
                    (byte) 0x30,  // READ
                    (byte) 0x04,  // page address
                   };
```

I succeed, but it's showing only empty bytes (00,00,00,00). So, i have a protocol document on how to get the data. The screenshot is below:

[image: Read Data Structure]

So, considering this request structure, i tried staring by byte command with

```
byte[] commands = new byte[]{
                    //NFCCmd
                    (byte) 0x06,

                    //Manufacture Code
                    (byte) 0x39,
                    (byte) 0x02,

                    //Card Identification Number
                    (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x01,
                    (byte) 0x80,
                    (byte) 0xD9

                    //Number of Service
                    (byte) 0x01,

                    //Service Code
                    (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x0B,

                    //Cnt
                    (byte) 0x02,

                    //BlockList Commands
                    (byte) 0x06,
                    (byte) 0x02,
                    (byte) 0x10,
                    (byte) 0x40
                  };
```

**PROBLEM:**  The ID consists of 7 bytes using the mTag.getId() or TagInfo android app(ref. Image below).

When i send commands, i get exception Tag is lost. I know, it's happening because of invalid commands. Can you help me out what will be proper byte commands[] sequence considering my device info.(cannot use Ndef so need to send raw commands only to fetch data)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Your read command looks OK, But you don't show how you are handling Tag detection as I would only expect Tag Lost exception when the tag goes out of range, are you using `enableForeGroundDespatch` or `enableReaderMode`?. A bad command should receive a NAK response,

Comment: Tag is in range but still it shows Tag Lost exception. I am using enableForeGroundDespatch. With the page read it works fine, but with different commands, Tag Lost exception.

Comment: The question is confusing, you talk about a "NXP MIFARE Ultralight" card and shown NDEF data and then talk about a device (not card) with possibly custom NFC commands? 
Is it a card or device?
OR is it this a device that pretends to be a card that returns an empty NDEF record of mimeType "application/sdbi" when queried using standard NFC read commands and has a custom command set?

Comment: I think your command is to big and you are reading the custom protocol spec wrong, but without the whole spec document it is difficult to tell (the colours of the items in the picture probably mean something) the way I read that is you send "06" and get back and byte array that contains details about the device or you send "00 0B" and get back data.

Comment: @Andrew Hi Andrew, thanks for your prompt responses. Actually, it is a NFC device with both compatible formats(NDEF, NfcA). But only NcfA with custom command set can be used according to their product communication diagram.

Comment: @Andrew The issue was to query the card and then get the device id from the response, and then query the device using that id to get the data. The procedure was not properly specified in their diagram but fortunately after trying different command sets, I am able to get the success response and parse data according to the specified format.

Thanks for your time.